# Retrieve from Oracle db key value pair

Tags: oracle, join

I need to retrieve 3 values with different key from a key value pair table.

My database schema as follows. I need to reach to table3 from table1 by taking the E_SUBID and then joining the table2 with E_SUBID. Once table1 and table2 are joined I need take to take E_CID from table2 to join it with table2 E_CID to get the "Attr_Value" keeping E_CID as a criteria.

Table1

```
------------------------
|E_SUBID| B_LocationID |
|1        100          |
|2        101          |
|3        102          |
```

Table2

```
-----------------
|E_CID | E_SUBID|
|10       1     |
|11       2     |
|12       3     |
```

Table3

```
--------------------------------- 
|E_CID | Attr_name | Attr_Value  |
|10       Product    Samsung     |
|10       Model      Smartphone  |
|10       usage      daily       |
|11       Product    Apple       |
|11       Model      Ipad        |
|11       usage      everyday    |
|12       Model      smartwatch  |
```

I have been successful to join table1,table2 and table3 but I cannot get the required output which as follows

**OUTPUT**

```
 |Product | Model      | Usage    |
  Samsung   Smartphone   daily  
  Apple     Ipad         everyday
  null      smartwatch    null
```

The query which joins table1, table2 and table3 as follows

```
select distinct t3.Attr_value as Product
from table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
where t1.E_SUBID = t2.E_SUBID and
      t2.E_CID = t3.E_CID  and
      t3.Attr_name=?????
 order by Product;
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a case like this, you can join to `table3` as often as you need to for each attribute `name` you wish to display:

```
select 
  p.attr_value product,
  m.attr_value "model", -- Quotes to escape reserved word
  u.attr_value usage
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.e_subid = t2.e_subid
left outer join table3 p on t2.e_cid = p.e_cid and p.attr_name = 'Product'
left outer join table3 m on t2.e_cid = m.e_cid and m.attr_name = 'Model'
left outer join table3 u on t2.e_cid = u.e_cid and u.attr_name = 'Usage'
order by 1;
```

**Edit**
Based on the comment, by making table3 optional (`outer join`) the query should return all rows and whether or not a `Model` or `Usage` or `Product` has been defined.

Comment: Thank you! your query did work as expected but i was just testing it with various scenario. I have updated my question with e_cid=12, your query doesn't gives the output as expected as shown in the question. Is there any fix to resolve it? I was trying to fix it but no success yet.

Comment: @user3384231 Ok so in the case of the new e_cid=12, what would you expect your results to show for "Product" and "Usage"? Nulls?

Comment: :Yes, it should be nulls

Comment: @user3384231 See the modified query.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you again. Will the use of Joins make the query run slowly when there is huge data or use of "Case" clause and aggregate function will make it more slow for query to run?

Comment: It all depends on your database, your indexes, the gathered statistics and more. However, in a database with the right indexes, joins should not appreciable affect performance. Actually, it's rare to find SQL not full of joins.

Comment: Can you please help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404188/oracle-update-query-with-joins

Answer (score 0):

Try as below ... Basically you are trying to transpose the rows to column in table3.

```
Select Product, "Model", Usage
From
(
Select 
t1.E_SUBID,
t2.E_CID,
Max(Case when T3.Attr_name = 'Product' Then T3.Attr_Value else null end) Product,
max(Case when T3.Attr_name = 'Model' Then T3.Attr_Value else null end) Model,
max(Case when T3.Attr_name = 'Usage' Then T3.Attr_Value else null end) Usage
From Table1 t1,
     Table2 t2,
     Table3 t3
Where 
    t1.E_SUBID = t2.E_SUBID
and t2.E_CID = t3.E_CID
group by t1.t1.E_SUBID,t2.E_CID
);
```

Comment: I did the same query but in the output I don't need E_subid from table1 and E_cid from table 2. Is there any workaround? In the output I just need "Product", "Model" and "Usage"

Comment: Yeah...put wrapper query and just select columns you need... I modified it

Comment: Can you please help me with the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404188/oracle-update-query-with-joins/25404807#25404807