# Oracle Update query with joins

Tags: oracle

I do know update clause doesn't work with joins in Oracle.

```
update table1 Pr
set code = (select t2.class_attr_value from table2 t2
where  class_attr_name = 'sample' and Pr.epcclass_id = t2.epcclass_id)
```

I would be thankful if someone can help me modify my query so that I don't get the error of SQL Command not ended properly.

Comment: Show us the structure and data of the `table1` and `table2` tables. Use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for this purposes. I can't see any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Query seems okay to me I just added Table Alias. Your query will update all records in table1.  What error you are getting...??

Suggestions,

a) Unless it's the intent that you want to update all records, add a where clause in the query to avoid updating all records...

b) If you are getting (ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row) then means corelated sub query (within brackets) is missing some condition to make it fetch only 1 row per epcclass_id.

```
update table1 Pr
set Pr.code = (select t2.class_attr_value 
               from table2 t2 
               where  t2.class_attr_name = 'sample' 
               and t2.epclass_id = Pr.epcclass_id 
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1 Pr INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t2.class_attr_name = 'sample' AND Pr.epcclass_id = t2.epcclass_id 
SET Pr.code = t2.class_attr_value
```

Comment: I am getting an error ORA-00971:missing SET keyword

Comment: For testing i am running the query on ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER